# "Only" vs "Single"

Tags: word-choice

Let's say we have list of items. Let's say we know that there's just one item in the list.

What is the proper way to refer to that very item, when we want to point it out that there're no other items in the list?

"The only list item" or "Single list item"?

Comment: Both can be used, but without further context, the *proper* version is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Single means one or alone; only means not more, exclusively.

I have a single friend.
I have only one friend.
I have only twelve friends.
 "The only list item" - so it will be right